# model binding asp.net core web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to bind model, but when i bind smartphone or laptop props, im losing myContnet main prop id, here is mainCont:

```
`namespace Bind.Models  
{
    public class MainCont
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public Device Device { get; set; }
    }
}`

using Bind.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bind
{
    public class DeviceModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }
            var model1 = new MainCont();

            var select = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("select").FirstValue;
            if (select == "SmartPhone")
            {
                var model2 = new SmartPhone();
                model2.screensize = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("screensize").FirstValue;
                model2.imei = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("imei").FirstValue;
                model1.Device = model2;
            }
            else if (select == "Laptop")
            {
                var model2 = new Laptop();
                model2.CPU = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("CPU").FirstValue;
                model2.GPu = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("GPu").FirstValue;
                model1.Device = model2;
            }

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model1);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

i cant set id, of course in DeviceBinder i wrote new mainCont(), and how can i solve it? Sorry for bad english ;)

Comment: You don't need to write your own `IModelBinder` - just define a DTO type.

Comment: Not required to do like this. Use DTO , automapper to bind DTO to database models

Comment: can you help me? i dont know how

Answer (score -1):

Firstly,you need to add a input in your view,so that you can pass the Id when form post.

Here is a demo:

Index.cshtml(I use a hidden input,if you want to edit the Id in the view,you can remove `hidden`):

```
 <form asp-action="create" asp-controller="home" method="post">
        <input asp-for="Id" hidden>
        <select id="select" name="select">
            <option value="SmartPhone">SmartPhone </option>
            <option value="Laptop">Laptop  </option>
        </select>
        <div id="sample"></div>
        <button type="submit">გაგზავნა</button>
    </form>
```

And then,in your CustomModelBinder,bind it to model:

```
public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }
            var model1 = new MainCont();


            //bind the Id here
            model1.Id= Convert.ToInt32(bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Id").FirstValue);
            var select = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("select").FirstValue;
            if (select == "SmartPhone")
            {
                var model2 = new SmartPhone();
                model2.screensize = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("screensize").FirstValue;
                model2.imei = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("imei").FirstValue;
                model1.Device = model2;
            }
            else if (select == "Laptop")
            {
                var model2 = new Laptop();
                model2.CPU = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("CPU").FirstValue;
                model2.GPu = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("GPu").FirstValue;
                model1.Device = model2;
            }

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model1);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Controller(When create view,I give the Id to the view):

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new MainCont {  Id=1});
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: of course, i did same but what if mainContent has lot props? if i get data without bind i get all props except device, and if i use binder i get only device and losing other props.  is any method to use binder to get device and other props bind automaticly?

Comment: Here is a document of  [ValueProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.ivalueprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0),It can only get value with GetValue(string) one by one,so it cannot be binded in custom model binding automaticly.